# Changing the wp-admin and wp-login.php URL via Bitnami Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I installed Wordpress by Bitnami on AWS - EC2.

My goal is to change the wp-admin and wp-login.php url. So I am trying to use this [Lockdown WP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/lockdown-wp-admin/) plugin. The problem is Bitnami wordpress refused to change the url.

I kept getting this error: 
Not Found
The requested URL /mylogin was not found on this server.

Any idea what is wrong with it? Any suggestion appreciated.

---

**UPDATED: New issue**

I found an issue what is the problem with my issue (above). I cannot find a good info how to fix this issue. What I have in my htaccess.conf file to force all http to https

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The only option is to remove those lines (above) and it is working. But I need to force all my domains / subdomains to HTTPS not HTTP. Any idea how to resolve it?

---

**Resolved**

I followed this [instructions](https://community.bitnami.com/t/change-url-from-http-to-https-in-bitnami-wordpress/47301/2). Now I am using his option 1 and it works so well. The only the option that I need to move my lines from htaccess.conf file to httpd-app.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin than i think your problem will be solved
[this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/protect-wp-admin/)

Comment: It doesn't work. Please see above my new updated info.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

I just launched a fresh instance of the Bitnami WordPress solution and installed the "Lockdown WP Admin" plugin. After enabling it, I went to the plugin's configuration and modified the "WordPress Login URL" to be "http://myip/test". I could log in to the application using /test without problems after saving the configuration.

I hope this information helps

Comment: Thank you for the info. It looks like I need to remove wordpress out of instance and re-install wordpress again. I will let you know if it fixed.

Comment: I found a issue what caused my problems with url. Could you please see above I provided more update info. Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please tell me why htaccess.conf doesn't perform well. I would like to know what is the different between htaccess.conf vs httpd-app.conf. The only option I have to move my lines from htaccess.conf into httpd-app.conf file. It works so well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad to hear you've solved the issue. The httpd-app.conf collects apache configuration to allow apps to be served by apache, htaccess.conf is a collection of .htaccess files that an application might (or might not) ship in the source code. Those .htaccess set permission directives that the web servers (like apache) interpret in order to deny/allow access to some directories, etc. We moved the .htaccess files to the htaccess.conf file because of security and performance issues.